# Jquery changing background-image not work with Bold tag

Tags: jquery

It's working with Div tag but not work with Bold tag. Any solution ?

```
$('#test').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8E45b/96/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8E45b/100/)**

`<b>` is an inline-element, means `width` and `height` do not apply to it. Add `display: inline-block`, and it will work. You should consider using a `<div>` for it.

```
<b id="test" style="width:400px; height: 100px;display: inline-block;"></b>
```

See also [w3c - css display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 0):

bold tag is an inline element, thus cannot get width and height properties. Try adding

```
display: block;
```

to your element style.

http://jsfiddle.net/8E45b/98/

Answer (score 0):

In your css add `display: block;`

```
#test { display: block; }
```

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8E45b/99/

Answer (score 0):

It is working...
you just have to fill in some text into bold tag ;)

You have to consider that the bold is dynamically increased by text.

```
<b id="test" style="width:400px; height: 100px;">This is a test</b>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8E45b/97/

Answer (score -1):

you need to display:block the b tag..

but? why the b tag